# CSS code with background video under header and body content

Tags: html, css, video, background

At the top of my page is a header, and is pulled in from a different file/folder using php.

I would like to have the background video fully covered under my content body and under my header. But whenever I put it, then it is under my content only and the header is disappearing for some reason. Also, when I put it for header only, then I will get it at the top only and the body will be empty with my normal content but without the background video.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 17px;
}

#myVideo {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  min-width: 100%; 
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo">
  <source src="https://www.belloo.date/upgrade/themes/landing2/images/bg.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

Comment: @JeremyW Thanks for the grammar changes, english is not my mothers language, therefor german. I appreciate it! :))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if is that what you are trying to achieve, but you can try add a z-index negative and do some css ajusts.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 17px;
}

#myVideo {
  position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    z-index: -100;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo">
  <source src="https://www.belloo.date/upgrade/themes/landing2/images/bg.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
<h1>Test</h1>
```

Comment: That worked like a charm! Hero, thank you so much. :D I tried hours and you got it in like 10 mins after my post omg

Comment: I appreciate your time and help!

Answer (score 0):

I do not know exactly what you mean, but maybe this will help you here.
I defined the header in css.

```
header {
  position: fixed;
  top:0px;
  left: 0px;
  right:0px;
  min-width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

and put the header tag

```
<header>My Header</header>
```

full html page

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 17px;
}
header {
  position: fixed;
  top:0px;
  left: 0px;
  right:0px;
  min-width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}
#myVideo {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  min-width: 100%; 
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
</head>
<body>
  <header>My Header</header>
<video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo">
  <source src="https://www.belloo.date/upgrade/themes/landing2/images/bg.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please justify and explain your answer, and make a proper snippet

Comment: Didn't work, but thanks for your answer! :) Flavio Caruso's answer worked very good!